# How to get the last n days data in DolphinDB

Tags: sql, dolphindb

I create a table as bellow,

```
timestamp=[2019.06.01T09:00:00.000 ,2019.06.02T09:00:00.000,2019.06.20T09:00:00.000]
sym = `MS`MS`MS$symbol;                 
price= 49.6 29.46 29.52 ;           
qty = 2200 1900 2100 ;              
t1 = table(timestamp, sym, qty, price)
```

Then I execute the the following code in DolphinDB Gui,
    select * from t1 
The record set is showed 
    [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUey5.png).
But I execite the following code,

```
days=1000*60*60*24
select * from t1 where timestamp > now()-days*30
```

The record set is null as showed 
     [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX9m4.png).

How to select the last n days data from the dolphindb table ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has minor data overflow issue. `days` is an integer (4 bytes) and the result of days * 30 exceeds integer's max value. Two ways to fix:

Method 1: convert constant 30 to 30l

```
days=1000*60*60*24
select * from t1 where timestamp > now()-days*30l
```

Method 2: use `temporalAdd` function

```
select * from t1 where timestamp > temporalAdd(now(), -30, 'd')
```